# How to position the DataTables button up to the top right corner of the browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to position my button up to the top right corner of the browser. I try the css but it fails. I there's other techniques that that datatables button can position up to the top right corner of the browser?

script:

```
<style>
     div.dt-buttons {
    float: right;
    margin-left:10px;
 }
</style>



 <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var buttonCommon = {
                exportOptions: {
                    format: {
                        body: function(data, row, column, node) {
                            return column === 5 ? data.replace(/[$,]/g, '') : data;
                        }
                    }
                }
            };

            var table = $('#detailsDataTable').DataTable({
                "scrollY": 500,
                "scrollX": true,
                "paging": false,
                "info": false,
                "searching": false,
                dom: 'Bfrtip',
                lengthChange: false,
                buttons: [
                    $.extend(true,
                        {},
                        buttonCommon,
                        {
                            extend: 'excelHtml5',
                            text: 'Export to Excel'
                        })
                ]
           });

            table.buttons().container().appendTo('#detailsDataTable_wrapper .col-sm-6:eq(0)');
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
div.dt-buttons {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Comment: You can use `position: absolute` then.